# JSON Object Modification in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

Can someone help me modifying the JSON Object using javascript, Currently I am using angular js and getting the JSON data from the file. But i want to modify the below JSON and process accordingly.

**Current JSON**

```
{
  "account": {
    "premise": {
      "zone": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "Tps John?!? \"':7",
          "type": "DOOR",
          "functionType": "ENTRY_EXIT",
          "sensor": [
            {
              "id": 1,
              "type": "DRY_CONTACT",
              "sourceType": "ZIGBEE",
              "serialNumber": "000d6f00030cdbcf.1",
              "model": "MCT-320 SMA",
              "manufacturer": "Visonic",
              "firmwareVersion": "0x00040008",
              "hardwareVersion": "1"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "name": "Motion Sensor $-*9$+%;47$9 %;:?2",
          "type": "MOTION",
          "functionType": "INTERIOR_FOLLOWER",
          "sensor": [
            {
              "id": 2,
              "type": "MOTION",
              "sourceType": "ZIGBEE",
              "serialNumber": "000d6f0004b2af93.1",
              "model": "NEXT K85 SMA",
              "manufacturer": "Visonic",
              "firmwareVersion": "0x0004000b",
              "hardwareVersion": "1"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

But From above JSON in the zone object have Sensor Object , but i want to keep only Sensor as below

```
{
  "account": {
    "premise": {
      "sensor": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "type": "DRY_CONTACT",
          "sourceType": "ZIGBEE",
          "serialNumber": "000d6f00030cdbcf.1",
          "model": "MCT-320 SMA",
          "manufacturer": "Visonic",
          "firmwareVersion": "0x00040008",
          "hardwareVersion": "1"
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "type": "MOTION",
          "sourceType": "ZIGBEE",
          "serialNumber": "000d6f0004b2af93.1",
          "model": "NEXT K85 SMA",
          "manufacturer": "Visonic",
          "firmwareVersion": "0x0004000b",
          "hardwareVersion": "1"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: just use `JSON.parse()` to create an object, remove properties you don't need and serialize it using `JSON.stringify()`

Answer (score 0):

To get your array of sensors, you just have to use `.map()` on the `account.premise.zone` of your initial object, like so :

`o.account.premise.zone.map(e=>e.sensor)`

You can reorganize the full Object like below :

```
let o = {
  "account": {
    "premise": {
      "zone": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "Tps John?!? \"':7",
          "type": "DOOR",
          "functionType": "ENTRY_EXIT",
          "sensor": [
            {
              "id": 1,
              "type": "DRY_CONTACT",
              "sourceType": "ZIGBEE",
              "serialNumber": "000d6f00030cdbcf.1",
              "model": "MCT-320 SMA",
              "manufacturer": "Visonic",
              "firmwareVersion": "0x00040008",
              "hardwareVersion": "1"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "name": "Motion Sensor $-*9$+%;47$9 %;:?2",
          "type": "MOTION",
          "functionType": "INTERIOR_FOLLOWER",
          "sensor": [
            {
              "id": 2,
              "type": "MOTION",
              "sourceType": "ZIGBEE",
              "serialNumber": "000d6f0004b2af93.1",
              "model": "NEXT K85 SMA",
              "manufacturer": "Visonic",
              "firmwareVersion": "0x0004000b",
              "hardwareVersion": "1"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
};
o = {
  account:{
     premise:{
         sensor: o.account.premise.zone.map(e=>e.sensor)
     }
  }
}
```

You may need to use `JSON.parse()` on the file data to convert it from a string to an object first. Small example :

```
JSON.parse("{foo:bar") //String
> { foo:bar }  //Object
```

Comment: you are creating object rather then editing in existing object .

Comment: this function has been branded into my brain with a hot poker, I work with large objects all the time. I clearly remember a before and after using `map()` :D

Comment: @Mahi I am not? `let o` is OP's initial object which I modify. Downvoting based on your misunderstanding isn't kewl :(

Comment: @xShirase what if you don't know the keys . so use `keys` of object  .

Comment: OP states that he ` want to modify the below JSON ` and get `the Sensor object`. feel free to add an answer if you feel like mine isn't relevant

Comment: @xShirase yeah what you were talking about

Answer (score 0):

This is not an optimized way but this may be one of the solution

```
var input = {}; //it is your input Object
var accountObj = { account: { premise: { sensor : [] }}};
input.account.premise.zone.forEach(function(zones) {
    zones.sensor.forEach( function(sensorObj) {
       accountObj.account.premise.sensor.push(sensorObj); 
    }); 
});
console.log(accountObj);
```

Comment: Thanks !! Here we are creating one empty object and pushing the values is there way we can modify existing. Because my original JSON have some other objects within premise .